# Edit Line Item error: Tax for amounts above 999.00 = NaN.N

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, line-items

I'm using the Edit Line Item Extension ver2.1 (biz.jmaconsulting.lineitemedit) on Civi 5.13.4 and the latest Drupal 7. I have a paid event where bookings are made via webform-civicrm.

If I edit a lineitem where the cost (unit price multiplied by quantity) exceeds 999.00, the tax amount calculates to NaN.N. I can submit the change but the tax amount is zero.
If I add a new line item where the amount exceeds 999.00 the tax amount again reflects as NaN.N, and I cannot save the change. 
Any ideas?
Many thanks, Davy

Comment: Can you try this PR if it helps to fix your problem https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.lineitemedit/pull/36 ?

Comment: Thanks @PradeepNayak. Afraid it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.lineitemedit/pull/42
Thanks for the help of Monish Deb and Joe Murray.